# How to copy a C# Array to an F# Array?

Tags: c#, f#

I need to "recast" a C# array, `IViewRx[] s`, as an F# WSDL type array, `WSDL.ServiceTypes.phoenixModel.view_rx[] rxList`. I want to do this in C#, before calling the F# method.

1. Is the below correct (Note the casting in the method call)?
2. Is there any other way to do this? (e.g., linq?)

```cs
Array rxList = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(WSDL.ServiceTypes.phoenixModel.view_rx), s.Length);
Array.Copy(s, rxList, s.Length);
    
await FsNetwork.Network.FsNetwork.DeleteRxListFromEncounterAsync(encounter, (WSDL.ServiceTypes.phoenixModel.view_rx[])rxList).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: If you know how to cast the array of type `'X` to type `'Y` in C#, this is the same as in F#. There is no difference between an "F# wsdl type array" and a "C# wsdl type array". On language level, F# uses type-safe arrays by default (all members are the same type), whereas in C# it is easier to have a mixed type array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both C# and F# uses a [common type system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/common-type-system). So the question is rather on how to convert from a array of one type to another type. A simple way to do it is to use linq:

```
var type2Array = type1Array.Select(item => /* convert the item to the target type*/).ToArray();
```

I have no idea on how to convert a object from a `IViewRX` to a `WSDL.ServiceTypes.phoenixModel.view_rx` since the types are not shown. If the target type inherit from the source type you can use [`.Cast<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netcore-3.1) or [`.OfType<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `.Select`